# Restrict X axis after stat_ecdf in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I change the X axis of `stat_ecdf`, but not change the calculation of ecdf?

Example code:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5))

# 1 to 5
ggplot(df, aes(x)) + stat_ecdf()

# 1 to 3, but stat_ecdf no longer calculated on the whole range
ggplot(df, aes(x)) + stat_ecdf() + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(NA,3))
```

The first graph gets to 1.0 by 5, as I'd expect:

[image: 1 to 5]

The second graph goes from 1 to 3 (good), but ends up at y=1 instead of y=0.66:

[image: 1 to 3]

This is likely because the `stat_ecdf` has been calculated over the visible window, but I want it calculated over all the data.

I'm pretty sure I've asked this before, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the points are removed before the summary statistics are calculated. Using `coord_cartesian()` gets around this. Try:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x)) + stat_ecdf() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 3))
```

Comment: How do you combine `coord_cartesian` with `geom_ribbon` ?  I'm trying to run the following code: `Graph <-  ggplot(df, aes(x=var_x,fill=year)) + stat_ecdf( geom = "ribbon")+coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 3))`. But I got an error. And I need to fill out the area under the curve. @eugene100hickey

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're missing the aesthetics ymin and ymax that geom_ribbon requires. You might try:

```
    Graph <-  ggplot(df, aes(x = var_x, fill = year, ymin = ..y..-0.1, ymax = ..y..+0.1)) + 
    stat_ecdf( geom = "ribbon") +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 3))
```

If that doesn't work, you might reply with the data frame, df, you're using and the error message you see. Thanks, Eugene